# jest.mock (intermediate value).... is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

I have the following code I want to test:

```
export class MetricBuilder {
  metricDimensions: MetricDimensionsType;
  metricName: MetricName;
  metricValue: number;

  constructor() {
    this.metricDimensions = [];
    this.metricName = '';
  }

  public withReferenceId = (referenceId: string) => {
    this.addDimension(MetricDimensions.ReferenceId, referenceId);
    return this;
  }
};
```

My test file looks like this:

```
jest.mock('../../app/metrics/MetricBuilder');

import { MetricBuilder } from "../../app/metrics/MetricBuilder";

import Mock = jest.Mock;

let MetricBuilderMock: Mock;

describe('blah', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    MetricBuilderMock = MetricBuilder as Mock;
    MetricBuilderMock.mockReset();
  });

  it.only('blah', async () => {
    const a = new MetricBuilder().withReferenceId('sldkfj');
    expect(MetricBuilderMock.mock.instances[0].withReferenceId).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

I get the following output from jest when executing the test:

```
  TypeError: (intermediate value).withReferenceId is not a function

      14 | 
      15 |   it.only('blah', async () => {
    > 16 |     const a = new MetricBuilder().withReferenceId('sldkfj');
         |                                   ^
      17 |     expect(MetricBuilderMock.mock.instances[0].withReferenceId).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      18 |   });
      19 | });
```

I can't figure out why this is happening as I thought jest would automock the constructor and all the methods of the module. Also, I am using typescript if that makes a difference here.

Comment: What are you actually *testing* here? Your test only exercises the mock.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I didn't read the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) carefully enough. It says that:

> Calling jest.mock('./sound-player') returns a useful "automatic mock"
> you can use to spy on calls to the class constructor and all of its
> methods. It replaces the ES6 class with a mock constructor, and
> replaces all of its methods with mock functions that always return
> undefined. Method calls are saved in
> theAutomaticMock.mock.instances[index].methodName.mock.calls.
>
> **Please note that if you use arrow functions in your classes, they will
> not be part of the mock.** The reason for that is that arrow functions
> are not present on the object's prototype, they are merely properties
> holding a reference to a function.

So the issue in my case was that I used arrow functions in my class, and the mock was empty.

The correct version of the class looks like this:

```
export class MetricBuilder {
  metricDimensions: MetricDimensionsType;
  metricName: MetricName;
  metricValue: number;

  constructor() {
    this.metricDimensions = [];
    this.metricName = '';
  }

  public withReferenceId(referenceId: string) {
    this.addDimension(MetricDimensions.ReferenceId, referenceId);
    return this;
  }
};
```